# Changing The Font Size On A Single Phrase In PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, font-size

Any help would be much appreciated.  So, I have a little application for work that displays a decision tree on PowerShell ISE.  You choose one of the options and it runs the script chosen. I am trying to make the menu a bit more attractive and user-friendly. As a result, I am looking to change the font-size on various Write-Host commands.  I know how to, for example, change the color:

```
Write-Host "Some text here." -foregroundcolor Red
```

I don't know; however, how to change the font size for that line of text.  Any ideas? I've looked everywhere, and the only info. I find is how to change the font for the entire ISE. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: This is not as trivial as it may seem. Basically you'll have to make a choice: 1) stick with the command line interface and accept that you can't control font settings, or 2) implement a GUI :-)

Comment: Ugh....that was my sneaking suspicion.  Thank you.